# php: Xpath ant unique ID

Tags: php, xpath

I work with PHP and Xpath and when save data i need insert unique id.
As in SQL auto increm.

How make this in Xpath?
File:

```
<info>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>test</name>
</info>
<info>
  <id>2</id>
  <name>some</name>
</info>
....
<id>5</id>
<name>testttt</id>
```

Comment: Your question can only be answered by a telepathist or a very lucky guesser. You need to provide input XML document _and_ the desired result.

Comment: From the tag wiki: *The primary purpose of XPath is to address parts of an XML [XML] document* . So, no input source modification. If you want a expression for building an unique id from each selected node of the input source, please say so.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a one-liner XPath expression that calculates the required new `id`. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it would be something like:

```
//info[last()]/id
```

So, with PHP's DOMDocument per example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('data.xml');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$lastId = $xpath->query('//info[last()]/id')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$nextId = $lastId+1;
```

The above assumes that the last node has the greatest ID.

In your case, it is impossible to compute the next ID with XPath alone. XPath 2.0 provides the `max` function to do that:

```
max(//info/id)
```

However, XPath 2.0 is not yet supported in PHP built-in libraries.

Comment: You assume the order of the nodes is reliable and reproducible.

Comment: Here is an approach to max/min in XPATH 1.0.  http://www.novell.com/communities/node/6431/again-power-xpath-or-missing-max-function

Answer (score 1):

> I work with PHP and Xpath and when
>   save data i need insert unique id. As
>   in SQL auto increm.
>
> How make this in Xpath?

**The new value for `id` can be calculated in a single XPath 1.0 expression**:

```
(//id)
  [not(. 
       <            
       (preceding::id|following::id|ancestor::id|descendant::id)
      )
  ]
    [1] +1
```

**Explanation**: This expression selects from all `id` elements in the document one that is not less than any other `id` element in the document. Then adds 1 to this value and we get the new value to use as an id.